# Google App Engine: Title-based URL Paths for entities

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I would like to create url paths for entities based on their titles.

For example, if the *title* of a Book entity is "**Romeo and Juliet**", I'd like the URL paths to be

```
http://example.com/book/romeo-and-juliet
```

Additionally, how would I handle this URL path if the book title is "**Romeo & Juliet**". Finally, is it recommended to use this approach, or should I just create URL paths using the entity's ID, like this:

```
http://example.com/book/4644337115725824
```

Grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you retrieve the book. App engine uses ndb and the key for each book should be unique. So there will be a difference between "Romeo & Juliet" and "Romeo and Juliet".

Also you will need to provide a way of uniqueness for every title and regarding books containing the same title (eg different countries) that will be hard.

An approach would be to use both. Generated id and a title like

```
/12345678/mybook
```

According to your comment then you are not puzzled by iniquity but SEO and url friendly strings. I recommend a search on that and you find more than you need. I am not an expert on URL firendly urls but they are cumbersome, and need escaping rules etc.

eg 'romeo & juliet' will have to be escaped due to spaces and the '&'.

So then you end up with creating conventions for your app. A simple rule for you example would be:

1. Replace '&' with 'and' on titles
2. Replace ' ' (spaces) with underscores '_'
3. ...

So you will be ending up with 'romeo_and_juliet' which is far more url friendly than 'romeo&juliet'.

If escaping strings in your concern mainly then use:

```
encoded_param = urllib.urlencode(book_title)
```

I like use urls like

```
/books/[key]/romeo_and_juliet
```

where [key] is the book `key`, either a string or an id.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Jimmy. That sounds like a good idea. I guess what I am really asking is: how do I make 'romeo & juliet' or 'romeo and juliet' URL friendly?